# Observable not triggering changes in child component

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I created a dynamic form component, following the Angular documentation. But when I try to add a value for the form after it has been created, the component does not update.

This is the question-service.service.ts

```
export class QuestionService {
  getQuestions(createQuestions: ICreateForm[]) {
    let questions: QuestionBase<string>[] = [];

    createQuestions.forEach((question) =>
      questions.push(this.createQuestion(question))
    );

    return of(questions.sort((a, b) => a.order - b.order));
  }
```

This is the component where the dynamic form is placed (add-quantity.component.ts):

```
questions$: Observable<QuestionBase<any>[]>;

  questionsTypes = [
    {
      key: 'name',
      label: 'Name',
      type: 'text',
      order: 1,
      value: '',
    },
    {
      key: 'quantity',
      label: 'Quantity',
      type: 'text',
      order: 2,
    },
    {
      key: 'unit',
      label: 'Unit',
      type: 'text',
      order: 3,
      value: '',
    },
  ];

  isLoading = false;
  productId = 0;

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private productService: ProductService,
    private toastService: ToastService,
    private questionService: QuestionService,
    private router: Router
  ) {
    this.questions$ = this.questionService.getQuestions(this.questionsTypes);
  }
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.params.subscribe((params) => {
      this.productId = params['id'];
    });
  
    this.isLoading = true;
  
    this.productService
      .getDetailedProductById(this.productId)
      .subscribe((product: IGetDetailedProduct) => {
        this.isLoading = false;
        this.questionsTypes[2].value = product.unit;
        let newQuestions$ = this.questionService.getQuestions(this.questionsTypes);
      });
  }
```

add-quantity.component.html:

```
<div class="header-section">
    <app-back-arrow></app-back-arrow>
    <h1 class="bold f-s-2">Add Quantity</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="form-container">
    <app-dynamic-form
      (formEvent)="onSubmit($event)"
      [questions]="questions$ | async"
    ></app-dynamic-form>
  </div>
```

This code creates the form correctly. But I want to update the form value for some fields and the variable this.questions$ is not being updated.

I read other question here saying that the *rxjs* method *of* does not work for this case but I can't figure the right solution.

Comment: There's no reason to use an observable if you're gonna re-create it every time. You need to call `next()` on the underlying subject to trigger change detection. For example you can define a private behaviour subject in your service with called `questions` and then expose that `asObservable()` to your component. When the questions are being updated, you can then call `questions.next(value)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I ended up removing the observable but it is working now!

Comment: that seems to always be the solution. lol. Remove the observable.